# Avoid creating backend s3 bucket when terraspace plan

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, terraspace

Sometimes I need to check what resources will be created within an environment without automatically creating state s3 bucket. I use `terraspace plan` but it automatically create an s3 bucket with the `TS_ENV` variable name as set in the `backend.tf`

Example:

`TS_ENV=prod terraspace plan STACK` creates a new s3 bucket for the prod environment.

Is there an option to disable that behaviour and only create the bucket when `terraspace up`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a 'aws.rb' file in 'config/plugins/' folder.

Then you can put the following  config to override the default behaviour:

```rb
TerraspacePluginAws.configure do |config|
  config.auto_create = false # set to false to completely disable auto creation
end
```

Source: https://terraspace.cloud/docs/plugins/aws/